# Firefox: Bookmarks on my own server?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, add-on, synchronize

I don't trust other servers (even Firefox's ;-)) and would like to store my bookmarks on my own server in order to synchronize them on different devices/PCs. So, similar to the "Sync" function within Firefox.

In the best case, there would also be a web interface to browse/manage bookmarks on my own server.

I think there is no add-on or extension for this, only different providers who store bookmarks on their servers.

How would be the best way to get this done?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds the best case for [wallabag](https://www.wallabag.org/en). You can even have it in a docker container.

> wallabag is a self hostable application for saving web pages: Save and classify articles. Read them later. Freely.

There is also an addon, [wallabagger](https://github.com/wallabag/wallabagger/) which you can link it to your own server.

References:

https://github.com/wallabag

https://wallabag.org/en/news/wallabagger-howto

Answer (score 1):

This post is your answer:
https://mozilla-services.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howtos/run-sync-1.5.html

[I wrote a post some time ago](http://linux.bersol.info/2013/08/16/sincronizar-favoritos-firefox-entre-varios-equipos-con-servidor-propio/), about this theme (*in Spanish*), when the Addon "**Xmarks**", still permit configure a custom server. It was very easy, you only need a *webdav* server, and you can sync Bookmars between this, and your devices with ***Firefox***. All right. But "**Xmarks**", removed the option. Thank you guys!, and now, I think we don't have any addon with this feature.

I'll try to do it with the tutorial of top answer, but its more complicated than older option.